# Why does on_message() stop commands from working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically, everything *appears* to work fine and start up, but for some reason I can't call any of the commands. I've been looking around for easily an hour now and looking at examples/watching videos and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. Code below:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('-debug'):
        await message.channel.send('d')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('Pong!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def add(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

The debug output I have in on_message actually does work and responds, and the whole bot runs wihout any exceptions, but it just won't call the commands.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

> Overriding the default provided `on_message` forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message`. For example:
>
> ```
> @bot.event
> async def on_message(message):
>     # do some extra stuff here
>
>     await bot.process_commands(message)
> ```

The default `on_message` contains a call to this coroutine, but when you override it with your own `on_message`, you need to call it yourself.

Answer (score -7):

Ascertained that the problem stems from your definition of `on_message`, you could actually just implement `debug` as a command, since it appears to have the same prefix as your bot:

```
@bot.command()
async def debug(ctx):
    await ctx.send("d")
```