# Betting "XP" Within a Command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I can't wrap my head around how to let a user bet X amount of "XP"(i use dollars) inside of a command. I've posted the simple coinflip command below with what I think should be the logic, but I am not 100% sure if I'm on the right track. I was wondering how I could call get_dollars for the user when they bet a random amount of money. I'm guessing that I will need to create something such as `betamount = enter authors bet amount` but I'm drawing a blank on how to handle the random amount they may put rather than hardcoding a fixed amount that forces the user to use.

```
client = discord.Client()

try:
    with open("cash.json") as fp:
        cash = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    cash = {}

def save_cash():
    with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def get_dollars(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in cash:
        return cash[id].get("dollars", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    betamount = ???
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!coinflip'):
        if get_dollars(message.author) < 0:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} you don't have enough money to bet.".format(message.author.mention))
        else:
            choice = random.randint(0,1)
            if choice == 0
                await client.add_reaction(message, '⚫')
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "The coin handed on heads!)
                if 'heads' in message.content:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "You've won ${}".format(betamount))
                    add_dollars(message.author, betamount)
                else:
                    if 'tails' in message.content:
                        await client.send_message(message.channel, "You've lost ${}".format(betamount))
                        remove_dollars(message.author, betamount)
            elif choice == 1:
                await client.add_reaction(message, '⚪')
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "The coin handed on tails!")
                if 'tails' in message.content:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "You've won ${}".format(betamount))
                    add_dollars(message.author, betamount)
                else:
                    if 'heads' in message.content:
                        await client.send_message(message.channel, "You've lost ${}".format(betamount))
                        remove_dollars(message.author, betamount)
```

Comment: Are they supposed to call your command like `!flipcoin 2.50`?

Comment: Correct, something like "!coinflip heads 23", of course ill add a check to see if the bet amount is larger than their total in get_dollars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a command like `!coinflip (heads/tails) (amount)` then you could use `x = message.content.split(" ")` to split the message into a list. With this you could do something like `outcome = x[1]` and `betamount = x[2]`.

I would also recommend that you then change `if 'tails' in message.content:` to `if outcome == 'tails'`. Otherwise a user could do something like `!coinflip heads (amount) tails` which would award them cash every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting into commands with arguments, (espescially once those arguments become [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) types like `discord.Member`), I would heavily recommend switching to using the `discord.ext.commands` extension.  It makes writing commands much simpler, and it means you get to move code out of the `on_message` event.  Here's how your command would look using `commands`:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def coinflip(ctx, guess: str, amount: float):
    guesses = ('heads', 'tails')
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess not in guesses:
        await bot.say("Invalid guess.")
        return
    author = ctx.message.author
    balance = get_dollars(author)
    if balance < amount:
        await bot.say(f"You don't have that much money.  Your balance is ${balance:.2f}")
        return
    result = random.sample(guesses)
    if result == guess:
        await bot.say("You won!")
        add_dollars(author, amount)
    else:
        await bot.say("You lost!")
        remove_dollars(author, amount)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Also keep in mind that if you start using commands you have to add [`await bot.process_commands(message)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331419/6779307) to the bottom of your `on_message` event

Comment: I was afraid I was going to have to change everything to this format. I guess it will be worth it in the long wrong, thanks so much for the response!