# Pass someones comment into a bots function (Discord

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to pass a message to a bots function? Like this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def message(ctx, user.message):
    if user.message == "xyz":
        await bot.say("Hi")
```

It would be good to pass the actual message and not a string with the same content.

Comment: You can also use the keyword-only syntax to capture the remainder of a message.  See [Keyword-Only Arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) from the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "Hi":
    await bot.send_message(message.channel,"Hello")
```

This way you use an event instead of a command so when you write "Hi" into the chat  the bot will catch it and run the method

If you want to pass something to the command function you can do so just like you would with a normal method

```
@bot.command()
async def example(something):
  print(something)
```

When you do `!example Hello There` the bot will print out `Hello` because from the strings it got as input (separated by whitespaces) it picked the first value and assigned it to your variable just like a normal program getting its input from the command line.

To catch all elements you can use `*args`

```
@bot.command()
async def example(*args):
  print(args)
```

which will return a tuple of all the values you gave from the chat.
`!example Hello There` will print out `('Hello', 'There')`

Comment: When i use the event the rest of the commands dont work(or activate).

Comment: [Here's the answer, you need to add an additional line at the end of on_message()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331419/9917504)

Comment: One last question. Can i treat the message.content as a normal string? As an Example can i write if "asdf" in message.content?

Comment: Yes, `content` returns a [normal string](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)

Comment: In "await bot.send_message(message.channel,"Hello")" what do you have to replace message.channel with?

Comment: If it's inside the event you don't have to replace it with anything since bot passes the message argument to the function and you can just take the `.channel` from it. [Check out the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)