# (Discord.py) Make a logger which saves conversations the bot is in

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py

how do I make a a logger bot in discord.py which saves conversation into a text file.

So for example the bot saves all chats in a folder called "chatlogs" and in discord **Server A** every time someone says something that the bot can see, the bot logs it in a file called **ServerA.txt** and when **Server B** adds my bot, it generates a file called **ServerB.txt** and saves all **Server B** conversations in there.

Answer (score 1):

In an [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event, open the file in append mode and write the latest message.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = message.guild
    if guild:
        path = "chatlogs/{}.txt".format(guild.id)  
        with open(path, 'a+') as f:
            print("{0.timestamp} : {0.author.name} : {0.content}".format(message), file=f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: @AlexWollan It should.

Comment: But how would I make it, make a new text file on join a new guild? and delete text file when bot is removed?

Comment: Did you try running this code?  It already creates a new file whenever it needs to.  To remove the file you would write an `on_bot_remove` event that deletes the file with that name.  Note that at the moment we only use server names, so if a server changes its name, events will get logged to a different file.  You can prevent this by using the server id as the file name instead.

Comment: I changed **@client.event** to **@bot.event** but I get this when I use bot (I use bot, because I have been using it throughout my code.) This is my error   **@bot.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'** also how would I use server ids instead?

Comment: You're decorating with `@bot.event()` instead of `@bot.event`

Comment: No it wouldn't.  See the documentation for [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), you can see an example of an `on_message` event there.

Comment: It does nothing, when I changed it to @client.event, but returns no errors when something is written

Comment: @AlexWollan If you remove the `file=f`, do you see the messages being printed to the console instead of to the file?

Comment: No I do not see the message, can I get your discord so we can talk quicker?

Comment: No (I'm on a work computer at the moment, so no discord).  Could you post the code that you have in your question?  There are a couple of gotchas (two `on_message` events for example), that are pretty easy to spot.

Comment: Make it `@bot.event` if you're using `bot`.

Comment: If you're using rewrite use `message.channel.guild.id` instead

Comment: I get this
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 220, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/cosmi/Desktop/__bot/main.py", line 60, in on_message
    path = "chatlogs/{}.txt".format(message.channel.guild.id)
AttributeError: 'DMChannel' object has no attribute 'guild'**

Comment: How do you want messages on private channels handled?  As for the other:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Comment: If it cant read private channels dont add them, if it can see add it.

Comment: Private channels don't have a server.  Which file would you save the messages to?

Comment: It does not save private channels

Comment: I edited it to ignore private channels.  If you want to log private channels, create an `else` clause that defines a `path` for those private channels, then move the `open` clause out of the `if` to after that `else`.