# Async events in other file

Tags: python, asynchronous, command, python-3.6, discord.py

I am making a discord bot using discord.py API. After doing some coding I've realized that I should keep the code clean and keep the commands and events in separate .py files. How could I do that event or command still listen for a trigger and are in separate files? I've tried doing it with `import` but it just imports classes. Example command:

`@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if ctx.message.channel.permissions_for(ctx.message.author).administrator is True:
        await client.send_message(member, settings.kick_direct)
        await client.kick(member)
        await client.say(settings.kick_message + member.mention + settings.kick_message2)
    else:
        await client.say(settings.permission_error)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the extension in the file where you create your `discord.py` client. See below example.

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client.load_extension('cog')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')

@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**cog.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class TestCog:

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def add(self):
        self.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % self.counter)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

Comment: It worked although it doesn't do anything. Bot doesn't respond on command.

Comment: I have tested the code on my side and it works fine. Are you placing both `bot.py` and `cog.py` in the same folder?

Comment: Yeah, same folder.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong then. Are you getting any sort of output? If not, try adding some print statements in both files to see if they load

Comment: Bot is definitely running, the file is loaded, although it doesn't execute a command.

Comment: So using both `!ping` and `!add` do nothing? What about the default `!help`?

Comment: I've implemented it with command I'd like to use if it's not a problem.

Comment: I can run commands in main file, but can't run this one command in standalone file.

Comment: Change `client.load_extension('kick')` to `client.load_extension('command')`. It has to be the file name, not the class name.

Comment: It is named kick, I just called the link like that. kick.py is running because i get printed checkstate 1 but the second print isn't showing up after giving a command. This means that extension is running, but the command isn't.

Comment: Your kick command should have `self` at the start, not the end. Also, in future please include full code samples in your initial question.

Comment: The example I gave works fine. See here: https://i.imgur.com/cgFtKgw.png

Comment: It has worked now. I've found out that one of my events interfered with my command, and blocked this command from being registered. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. For future reference, if the interfering event was `on_message`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was an `on_message` event.