# Wait for message discord python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def coolest(ctx):
      await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Say hello')
      msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='hello')
      await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello.')
```

Its not working. And no errors are appearing. I tried in different way and have done in on_message. But dont know why its not working in client.commands. Help.

Comment: Are you sure you run the command with some event loop? `asyncio.run` or anything more low level: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio-example-sleep

Comment: What else is in your file that could be interfering with this?  [Do you have an `on_message` that stops commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working).  Remove everything else in your file, and see if you can get just this component to fail.  You should be left with just `from discord.ext.commands import Bot`,  `client = Bot(command_prefix='!')`, this code, and `client.run("token")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to `message` throughout this coroutine.  Change all these references from `message` to `ctx.message`

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def coolest(ctx):
      await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Say hello')
      msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, content='hello')
      await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Hello.')
```

Unless `message` is defined in an enclosing scope, you should be seeing an error when this happens.  You should double check any error-handling code you have to make sure it isn't suppressing unexpected error messages.