# Discord Bot does not respond to commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been developing a discord bot for the past month, I've been doing commands using on_message listeners, which according to alot of people online isn't very ideal, so I decided to take it to the next step and do it properly, I looked at the documentation and came up with this basic code:

```
import discord #import all the necessary modules
from discord import Game
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client() #define discord client
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') #define command decorator

@bot.command(pass_context=True) #define the first command and set prefix to '!'
async def testt(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!!')

@client.event #print that the bot is ready to make sure that it actually logged on
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as:')
    print(client.user.name)
    await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="in rain ¬ !jhelp"))

client.run(TOKEN) #run the client using using my bot's token
```

Before going through the pain of implementing all of my commands to this new way of doing things, I wanted to test it so I know that it works for sure and sadly, it didn't, I went through a bunch of posts and documentation again but I couldn't spot what I did wrong, the bot logs in fine to the proper user and I just can't seem to figure out and understand what the problem is, I am probably missing something obvious yet again

Could anyone help, that would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By saying `client = discord.Client()` you make an discord client which will be online of course (If it isn't even online tell me) and you made an discord bot with `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`. The discord bot won't run, only the discord client will because you only did run the client with `client.run(TOKEN)`. So a quick preview of what your code should be and would hopefully work:

```
import discord #import all the necessary modules
from discord import Game
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') #define command decorator

@bot.command(pass_context=True) #define the first command and set prefix to '!'
async def testt(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!!')

@bot.event #print that the bot is ready to make sure that it actually logged on
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as:')
    print(bot.user.name)
    await bot.change_presence(game=Game(name="in rain ¬ !jhelp"))

bot.run(TOKEN) #run the client using using my bot's token
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, the bot logs in but doesn't respond, for testing sake's it responds perfectly to a on_message listener, does this code work for you?

Comment: @Myronaz See [Why does on_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Comment: Oh I see, I still need an on_message listener for something so this was useful
Thanks alot for helping me figure this out!

Comment: No problem, and I personally use on_message with my discord bots