# How to make bot sleep and stop responding to commands (or on_messages)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that makes the bot basically in sleep mode, this is meant to make the bot stop responding to commands (or on_messages if possible)
Trying to use `client.pause (Boolean)` and it didn't give errors i don't know what it does exactly but nothing happens
Below is where I am so far.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def sleep(ctx):
    client.pause = True

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def awake(ctx):
    client.pause = False
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of database backend where you can save a variable for something like `is_asleep`?

Comment: No, I'm not using it

Comment: Nevermind, this would be a per instance variable, although I would suggest some way of persisting variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `on_message` to override the bot from invoking commands automatically, then build some logic for you to decide decide it doesn't want to take any commands anymore *(aka sleep)*. But be sure you have the option as the bot owner to awaken it or you're SOL and will need to restart.

Something like the following should work.

*<sub>The assumption in my code being you're using the rework and f-strings are acceptable, but the logic is here and very little needs to be changed I think for it to be compatible with the `async` version.</sub>*

## Basic control flow:

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class MyBot(commands.bot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix = '!', description=None):
        super().__init__(command_prefix, description)
        #you could just say False here but if you
        #want to start the bot asleep here's a decent way to do it.
        self.asleep = kwargs.get('asleep', False)

async def is_owner(obj):
    owner = self.application_info().owner
    return obj.author == owner


async def on_message(self, message):
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
    is_owner = client.is_owner(ctx):
    
    if is_owner or not self.asleep:
        self.invoke(ctx)

...
```

**owner.py** *- or wherever you keep your* "bot owner only" *commands.*

```
from discord.ext import commands

...

@commands.command()
async def sleep(self, ctx):
    self.bot.asleep = True
    await ctx.say(f"I am now asleep, I will only respond to {ctx.author}")


@commands.command()
async def awaken(self, ctx):
    self.bot.asleep = False
    await ctx.say("Ahhh, just woke up! Ready to take commands!")

...
```

**launcher.py**

```
import MyBot

...

bot = MyBot(...)
bot.load_extension("path/to/owner_py_file")

...
```

<sub>I came up with this based on how [RDanny](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/dd982baa048efeb64c744c7c69b8bb5a09f1d7d4/bot.py#L125) bot assign's it's Database to each context before a command is called. It's a very well written bot that the owner has put out the source code publicly for educational purposes.</sub>

---

## Edit

#### to accommodate your current build

For your case, I assume you're just creating a bot using something like `client = commands.bot(...)` this is again pretty cookiecutter and won't allow you to leverage any power you'd gain from subclassing `bot`, but you could just implement the following and gain the same functionality as above:

```
client = commands.bot(...)
client.asleep = False
```

Then for the commands that you showed in the question:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def sleep(ctx):
    client.sleep = True

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def awake(ctx):
    client.asleep = False
```

Then for the `on_message` override. **Please reference:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331419/225020) to help explain why this works. <sub>or even the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands). hint hint</sub>

```
async def _is_owner(obj):
    owner = self.application_info().owner
    return obj.author == owner


@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
    is_owner = _is_owner(ctx):
    
    if is_owner or not self.asleep:
        client.invoke(ctx)
```

If the above implementation fails to work for you then you can give the method described in the answer I linked just above:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    is_owner = _is_owner(ctx):
    
    if is_owner or not client.asleep:        
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

<sub>**Please note** I don't know how you're module is structured but if this is being done within a class, and you define `_is_owner(...)` within that class, you will need to use `is_owner = self._is_owner(...)` although this could be defined elsewhere.</sub>

Comment: Says kwargs is not defined, also I'm not using cogs so i may have messed up somewhere while converting from cogs

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using cogs? Also, if not then instead of `self.invoke` just return, Then put all your other "command" logic after that.

Comment: hmm. that does quite fix it, I'm not using cogs because i already started scripting my bot and wasn't using cogs and It's to much scripts so to turn them into cogs'll take a while

Comment: You’re making things even harder for yourself in the long run. Also, “that doesn’t quite fix it” isn’t giving me any information to help you.

Comment: It doesn't fix the error that kwargs isn't defined, Is there any way you can remake the scripot without the cogs?

Comment: I edited my answer. Also, If you're using super.init in Python 3, then you don't need the args/kwargs, I failed to remember this for a second. That was a Py2 thing. Just taking that out should fix it, unless there's an underlying issue elsewhere. Nevertheless, to just stick with what you're doing now; the code in my edit should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_prefix function to change the bot command so that it won't respond to any public prefixes.

```
backup_prefixes=['.','!','s.','k!']
prefixes = ['.','!','s.','k!']
def get_prefix(bot, msg):
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(*prefixes)(bot, msg)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def resume(con):
    for i in backup_prefixes:
        prefixes.append(i)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def pause(con):
    prefixes.clear()
    # prefixes.append("an unknow prefix so it can't be invoked") #Ex: aslkdjflkj2k4lkj21312kj
    prefixes.append(',')
```

You can additionally add more if statements to make sure that only certain users can use the command to mute the bot so that it won't respond to other users.