# Discord.py bot - ping command not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm just sarting out with discord bots and haven't been using python for very long either. I'm making a currency bot, the currency being ep, that keeps track of user's wealth and saves everything in a json file. I got this working before but wanted to use a different way of writing it.

My initial way -

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith('EP.PING'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Ping.")
```

My (hopefully better way) -

```
@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')
```

The error messages -

```
File "f:/Python Programs/EP Bot/EP Bot V2.py", line 19, in <module>
    @client.command()
  File "F:\Python 3.6.4\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 296, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg.format(self.__class__, name))
AttributeError: '<class 'discord.client.Client'>' object has no attribute 'command'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001E73CDBBDA0>
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001E73CDCE0B8>
```

Help with this would be much appreciated and if you think that my initial method is better then that's fine too, I just think that this is far easier if it works.

If you know of any reference code or templates then that would be awesome!

Comment: I'm not an expert on discord.py or decorators, but for consistency, shouldn't `@client.command()` be `@client.command`?

Comment: @RandomDavis No.  `client.command()` is a function that returns a decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instead of `discord.Client`.  `Bot` is a subclass of `Client`, so you should be able to just drop it in as a replacement and everything will start working

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot('!')

# Rest of your code is unchanged
```

Keep in mind that if you want to have `on_message` and `command`s, you need to modify your `on_message` to support them.  See [Why does on_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Comment: Thanks! this was really confusing me

Answer (score 1):

I know that I am late but the answer is that you always require ctx in custom command. Your code should look like this:
`@client.command() async def ping(**ctx**): await client.say('Pong')`