# trying to delete all messages from a spesific channel breaks the whole bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want to make the user type !join to join in a game but delete all messages in it so it doesn't get full. But when i do this it deletes all the messages in that channel, but it breaks all the other parts of the bot.

I tried await message.delete() and await message.channel.purge(limit=1).

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(590978944904331274)
    if message.channel == channel:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)


client.run(token)
```

it works but breaks the rest of the bot.

Comment: Assuming you mean the commands stop working, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331419/9083371

Comment: thanks @Benjin that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the awnser was

From the documentation:

```
Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a bot.process_commands(message) line at the end of your on_message. For example:

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The default on_message contains a call to this coroutine, but when you override it with your own on_message, you need to call it yourself.

@benjin commented this on the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(590978944904331274)
    if message.channel == channel:
        await message.delete()
```

or in your !join command
if you are using

```py
async def join(ctx):
    #do your code
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

The `await ctx.message.delete()` will delete the users message/command when the command is used.

The `await message.delete()` will delete anyone's message even conversation.