# Discord Moderator Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I can't figure out the on_message event
Everything seems to be correct, there are no errors in the console, but the bot does not respond to messages

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

hello_words = ["Hello", "Hi", "qq", "w'zz"]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready") # if the bot running


async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send("Hello")

client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `client.event` decorator to the `on_message` function. You should also add a check to make sure the bot does not respond to its own messages.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot: 
        return
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send("Hello")
```

Comment: Dont work ;(
I have a function with the command event
He is working fine

`
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hi(ctx):
 await ctx.send("Hi!")
`

Comment: @DmitriyMakarov See [Why does on_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working) for a solution to that problem