# On_message command not letting other commands work

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is the code I am using. This works, but the rest of the commands do not work.
How can I make it so it does not affect other commands?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!'):
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands also use some sort of `on_message` in the background therefore by adding your own on_message, you're making it take it as you want to use your own on_message thus blocking the default one. To make it use both, add `await client.process_commands(message)` to the end of your on_message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!'):
        await message.delete()
    await client.process_commands(message)
```