# Discord.py - Bot not sending messages & no error messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I'm working on making my own bot for my server and after a while I finally found a string for autorole & role assignment that worked.
I then kept on adding another string for the bot simply replying "Hello". As soon as I add that the role commands won't work anymore. Once I take it out it works again.
On the other hand I have a 8ball and a dice roll command that works with and without the Hello Command
I have no idea what is the problem...

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='entrance')
    await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention} to Dreamy Castle! \n Please make sure to read the rules!')
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Peasants")
    await member.add_roles(role)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('+acceptrules'):
        member = message.author
        role1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='The People')
        await member.add_roles(role1)

@client.event #this is the hello command
async def on_message(message):
    message.content.lower()
    if message.content.startswith('Hello Conny'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Comment: It's already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` and `elif` not 2 different functions for same event.

Also you might need [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) for a fully functional commanded bot.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('+acceptrules'):
        member = message.author
        role1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='The People')
        await member.add_roles(role1)
    elif message.content.lower().startswith("hello conny"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Tried it out but it doesn't react to either command and I'm not still not getting an error... it's just not doing anything

Comment: add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of on_message, check the edited code

Comment: I tried that too but today it isn't reacting to any commands at all...

Comment: Ohay I fixed a few little errors and they're all working! Thank you so much!