# Python Discord bot won't run commands, but will run on_message(), why is that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

print("Starting bot...")

TOKEN = (the token)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')


# answers with the ms latency
@client.command(name='ping', pass_context = True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms ')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

it runs any on_message commands but not anything else.
I've looked at many tutorial sites and pages in S-O but none seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for posting the question. It would be helpful if you provided a specific example of the behavior, e.g. what did you try to run and what was a result? Was there any exception thrown, and what was it? What else did you try to change this behavior, e.g. parameter changes...

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, there was no exception thrown, just I say a command and it doesn't happen. They will only respond to on_message(). Do I write the command before the on_message()s?

Comment: The on_message() is below the function and yet it makes no difference.

Comment: hmmm... it works if i remove the on_message function. why is that?

Comment: check this question, it may already have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Comment: Yes, I had fixed it, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check TeilaRei's last post, you need to add a line to to on_message().