# Discord.py can't check for messages and check for commands at the same time

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm using

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

to check for messages sent by users.
I'm also using

```
@client.command(aliases=['a'])
async def a(ctx):
```

to check if a command is being run. when i leave the on message in, the command part won't run. what do i do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `on_message` event, it blocks your commands. In order to prevent this, you can use `await client.process_commands(message)`. You just have to add this line of code in the last line of your `on_message` event.