# Problem using when_mentioned with custom prefix

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**What im trying to do:** I want my bot to send a message when its mentioned, i don't wanna use it as prefix just send a single message when mentioned.

**My problem:** It only reacts to the `when_mentioned` and will not react to the normal commands.

**What i have tried:**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"title)", color=0x7289da)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnailurl")
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: When you modify the main `on_message` handler, you have to add a call to `process_commands(...)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.mentions[0] == bot.user:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="title",
                            description=f'My prefix is `{bot.get_prefix(msg)}`',
                            color=0x7289da)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="thumbnailurl")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.mentions[0] == client.user:
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"title)", color=0x7289da)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnailurl")
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: This won't fix OP's issue since they are not processing commands.