# Discord.py - on_message() conflicting with bot command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

**Issue:** When I set up `on_message` then the sendGif command does not work. When I comment out `on_message` then it works perfectly.

**My Code:**

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
#----------------------------------------------------------#
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == bot.user:
return
content = message.content
print(content)
if "test" in content:
await message.channel.send("You test" + message.author.mention)
await message.add_reaction(":haha:")
else:
pass
#----------------------------------------------------------#
```

```py
@bot.command()
async def sendGif(ctx, link):
embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed GIF")
embed.set_thumbnail(url="Gif Link here")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1):

hi just to the end on_message add

```py
await bot.process_commands (message)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: Please add a code example (use tic ` marks to make a code block) URLs can go change or websites can go down.

Answer (score 1):

In your `on_message` event reference, you would have to add the line `await bot.process_commands(message)`. The [`discord.py` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) explains the [`process_commands` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands):

> This function processes the commands that have been registered to the bot and other groups. Without this coroutine, none of the commands will be triggered.

> By default, this coroutine is called inside the `on_message()` event. If you choose to override the `on_message()` event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well.

So, your `on_message()` event reference should look something like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    content = message.content
    print(content)
    if "test" in content:
        await message.channel.send("You test" + message.author.mention)
        await message.add_reaction(":haha:")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```