# I need help fixing this @bot.event loop

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author ==bot.user or message.author.bot:
    return
  mention=message.author.mention
  if message.content == "$hug":  
    await message.channel.send(f"Hugs {mention} back")
    return
```

this is the code i am using to run the loop, it works but turns off the rest of my code. I was wondering what it is in this code thats shutting the rest off.

```
Im using replit and am using one of the discord.py templates.
@bot.command()
async def dink(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Donk!")
```

^thats one of the codes that are not working with the hug event.

Comment: No errors are showing up its just not running the rest of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 0):

```py
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author ==bot.user or message.author.bot:
        return
      mention=message.author.mention
      if message.content == "$hug":  
        await message.channel.send(f"Hugs {mention} back")
        return
      elif message.content == "dink":
        await message.channel.send("Donk!")
        return
```