# Is there a way to code a "say" command into my discord bot with python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried different options, and this one was the one that I desired the most, but I cannot seem to get it working. Could I get some help? (Sorry I am very new to coding)

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@bot.command()
async def speak(ctx, *, text):
  if ctx.message.author.id == ID here:
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    
    await ctx.send(f"{text}")
  else:
    await ctx.send('I need text!')
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Cannot get it working"? E.g. error messages, wrong text etc.

Comment: Can you describe the way how it should behave? I copied it and no errors occured...

Comment: Yes so in the terminal I do not get any error notifications, but when I try to use it in discord, it does not work. I use "-say (message)" but it does not cooperate. Am I supposed to execute it differently?

Comment: Did you replace the `ID here` part with an actual ID? Did you start the bot?

Comment: Yes I did both. I have run the bot before and have a few async def on_message commands, it is just this one that I am having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement makes little sense here. It is best to set up the condition differently, that you want `text` once and if that does not happen, then there is an `else` argument.

I don't know if this is relevant either, but apparently it looks like you want only one person to be able to execute this command. For the **owner** there would be:

```py
@commands.is_owner()
```

But if you want to make it refer to **another person** use:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner() # If you want to set this condition
async def say(ctx, *, text: str = None):
    if ctx.message.author is not ID_You_Want:
        await ctx.send("You are not allowed to use the command.")
        return # Do not proceed
    if text is None: # If just say is passed with no text
        await ctx.send("Please insert a text.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(text) # Send the text
```

*Optional:* You can also delete the command that was send with `ctx.message.delete()`

Your command is not executing because you defined `client` and `bot`.
Simply remove `client = discord.Client()` and you will be fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks!

Also; with the delete message, I wanted it so it deletes the trigger command. Would that still work?

Comment: I have also been executing the command like this in my server: -say hi.

Is that the correct way to do it? Or have I been doing to wrong?

Comment: You can't use `client =` and `bot =`, delete `client` and you will be fine. If you want to delete the trigger command you can use my `Optional` method.

Comment: It says it does not have any errors, but it still is not working. I am typing in discord: "-say hello" and it won't work. My other commands are working though.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your full code somewhere and share a link?

Comment: Yeah sure do you use replit?

Comment: Just copy and paste it there and share the link.

Comment: Well, you have to use `@bot.command` **AND** `@commands.is_owner()`

Comment: Then your `on_message` events must be blocking your code. The arrangement is also a bit vague. First should come the `on_ready` event, then the `on_message` events and then the commands. To fix the `on_message` error have a look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Comment: So I would put the await bot.process_commands(message)at the end of the on_message?

Comment: Yes, as the post said.

Comment: Also, do you have the freedom to edit the code itself?

Comment: I can't edit it, also do not see any changes for now.

Comment: I think the "is not" on line 17 is not working

Comment: Continue the conversation in the Replit chat