# Discord bot command being received, but not executing command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

asking another question. This time more complicated (for me at least). So i'm making a discord bot and when I do for example k!ship, it will print "a" (this is there for debugging) but wont show the embed. When I remove the keyword detector for the words "madoka" and "magical girl", evrey thing is fine. I assume this code bit is the problem. Here is the full code. (But not the token ofc) Also the couple_list has the names removed, there friends names so it makes sense.

```
# Imports

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

# Credentials
TOKEN = 'use your imagination and imagine a token here :)'

# Create bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='k!')


# Startup Information
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "madoka" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("✨being meguca is suffering✨")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "magical girl" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("✨being meguca is suffering✨")


# Commands

@client.command()
async def jupiter(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Peanut Butter')


# lists for commands
couple_list = ['imagination™']
ship_list = ['Madoka Kaname', 'Homura Akemi', 'Sayaka Miki', 'Mami Tomoe', 'Kyo(u)ko Sakura', 'Hitomi Shizuki',
             'Kyosuke Kamijio']
ship_dis = ['It would be so intense!', 'A nail biter!', 'Its the best pick I got!']


# couple command

@client.command()
async def couple(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=('In my opinion, ' + (random.choice(couple_list)) + ' and ' + (
        random.choice(couple_list)) + ' would be a great pair!'), color=0x8b0000)
    embed.set_footer(text="What a nice couple ❤♥♥")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


# ship command
@client.command()
async def ship(ctx):
    ship_cmd = discord.Embed(title=('In my opinion, ' + (random.choice(ship_list)) + ' and ' + (
        random.choice(ship_list)) + ' would be a great ship!'), color=0x8b0000)
    ship_cmd.set_footer(text=(random.choice(ship_dis)))
    ship_cmd.set_thumbnail(
        url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/801105512933752882/845050099678576640/unknown.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=ship_cmd)
print("a")

# status
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='TOO MANY NAGITO EDITS!!'))



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Any help solving this would be great!
-Jake

Comment: You can't have multiple `on_message` events, your code works fine for me. `a` is printed because you have not indented it correctly, it has to be under your `await` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is pretty much easy to handle. You have actually added `on_message` function multiple times which is not how you do it.

You use `if` statements and thus you can use them by keeping them all in one single function.

For Example:

I am going to perform two task both of which will be in `on_message` defined only once.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "Hello" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Hi!")
    if "Bye" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Bye!")
```

So this shows you how can you do it. But now we are implementing it in your code. So if we compile all of that in one function:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "madoka" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("✨being meguca is suffering✨")

    if "magical girl" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("✨being meguca is suffering✨")
```

Now this will help you let you use all of it correctly.

But now, I saw that you are using that you are creating `command()` as well, so you have to know one thing. If you do not add a `process_command()` statement then your commands won't work at all. You would literally keep trying to find error but your won't know. So I am making it clear.

The following statement is very important when you are trying to use `event` with the `command()`.

```
await client.process_command(message)
```

Now Let's add it to the your code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "madoka" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("✨being meguca is suffering✨")

    if "magical girl" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("✨being meguca is suffering✨")
    
    await client.process_command(message)
```

---

This will surely help you with the error. If still you have any problem, please ask my in the comments.

Thank You! :D

Comment: Thanks! I swear i'm not crying in joy! Ha... anyways thanks a lot! It definitely works!

Comment: Anytime Mate! :D