# Python Discord Bot, client.command stops working if client.event is in script

Tags: python, discord.py

i made a discord bot in python but every time i add this to my script, the commands stop working:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  message=message.content
  print(message)
```

Does somebody know, how to fix that?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your code:

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

for Example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

## Don't Use In "Cogs".

Comment: Hello, first thank you really much for helping me, but i get this error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author`
Do you or someone else how I can fix that?

Comment: edit you'r Q and add all of on_message code.