# Everything stopped because of one event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 872448587571789834:
        data = message.content.split(" ")
        user = re.sub("\D", "", data[0])

        user_object = client.get_user(int(user)) or await client.fetch_user(int(user))
        user = user_object
        await user_object.send("Hey, thanks for up-voting me on top.gg, here take 10,000 coins and a special role as an award ")
        #voted = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=" Voted for Legend Moderation")
        await open_account(user_object)

        users = await get_bank_data()

        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += 10000

        with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
    else:
        return
```

So, what I'm doing here. I'm checking if there is a message sent in that specific channel id and the id contains a user so its working the code works but all the other commands don't work when I put it

Comment: if the channel ID doesn't match, you just return instead of processing the message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `client.process_commands(message)`

example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  await client.process_commands(message)

  if message.channel.id == 872448587571789834:
    data = message.content.split(" ")
    user = re.sub("\D", "", data[0])

    user_object = client.get_user(int(user)) or await client.fetch_user(int(user))
    user = user_object
    await user_object.send("Hey, thanks for up-voting me on top.gg, here take 10,000 coins and a special role as an award ")
    #voted = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=" Voted for Legend Moderation")
    await open_account(user_object)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += 10000

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
else:
    return
```

see if using `client.process_commands(message)` works.

Comment: look at the change i did to the script

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `@client.event` to `@client.listen()`