# discord.py bot doesn't respond

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am relatively new to discord.py, I am making a bot, but with certain commands, or things that I put, the bot stops responding to the commands (when it previously worked), I can't figure out how to fix it, the bot turns on, but does not respond to any command

this is the zone where is the new

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import urllib.request
import json
import keep_alive
import time
import asyncio
import urllib
import datetime
import pymongo
import levelsys
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = discord.Client()

talk_channels = []

cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://endercraft46:<______>@enderbot.93khp.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

levelling = cluster["discord"]["levelling"]

bot = Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
async def on_ready(self):
  print(f'Conectado a {self.user}')

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  print(f'En linea!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')
    while 1:
        urllib.request.urlopen("https://Enderbotpy.endercraft26.repl.co")
        await asyncio.sleep(500)

############################LEVELSYS###################################################

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  stats = levelling.find_one({"id" : message.author.id})
  if not message.author.bot:
      if stats is None:
        newuser = {"id" : message.author.id, "xp" : 100}
        levelling.insert_one(newuser)
      else:
        xp = stats["xp"] + 5
        levelling.update_one({"id":message.author.id}, {"$set":{"xp":xp}})
        lvl = 0
        while True:
          if xp < ((50*(lvl**2))+(50*lvl)):
            break
            lvl += 1
        xp -= ((50*((lvl-1)**2))+(50*(lvl-1)))
        if xp == 0:
          await message.channel.send(f'felicidades {message.author.mention}, subiste de nivel a **nivel: {lvl}**!')

@bot.command()
async def rank(self, ctx):
  stats = levelling.find_one({"id" : ctx.author.id})
  if stats is None:
       embed = discord.Embed(description='no has enviado ningun mensaje, por lo tanto, no tienes rango')
       await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    xp = stats["xp"]
    lvl = 0
    rank = 0
    while True:
      if xp < ((50*(lvl**2))+(50*lvl)):
        break
      lvl += 1
    xp -= ((50*((lvl-1)**2))+(50*(lvl-1)))
    boxes = int((xp/(200**(1/2) * (lvl)))*20)
    rankings = levelling.find().sort("xp",-1)
    for x in rankings:
        rank += 1
        if stats ["id"] == x["id"]:
          break
          embed = discord.Embed(tittle="{}'s level stats".format(ctx.author.name))
          embed.add_field(name="Name", value=ctx.author.mention, inline=True)
          embed.add_field(name="XP", value=f"{xp}/{int(200*((1/2)*lvl))}")
          embed.add_field(name="Rank", value=f"{rank}/{ctx.guild.member_count}")
          embed.add_field(name="Progress Bar [lvl]", value=boxes * ":blue_square:" + (20-boxes) * ":white_large_square:", inline=False)
          await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The new thing I add is a level system, but somewhere it is giving fault

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is in your `on_message` event as it takes command as a normal message to fix this you just need to add `await self.client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the `on_message` event

Comment: No problem can u just mark it as verifyed answer

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.