# Discord.py Why will this client.command not work?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("uno regeln"):
        await message.channel.send('http://www.uno-kartenspiel.de/spielregeln/')        

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Ok")
     
client.run("TOKEN")
```

When I try to run this and use -test nothing happens
But why?
I looked in the docs but in my opinion everything is fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 0):

As given by the link provided by @Lukasz Kwieciński,
you need to change it to:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("uno regeln"):
        await message.channel.send('http://www.uno-kartenspiel.de/spielregeln/')        
    await bot.process_commands(message)
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Ok")
     
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Is Ready")
    
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="TYPE THERE ANYONE"))

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Ok")

client.run('YOUR TOKEN')
```

Try this

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question at all & does other random stuff that is unrelated. 2) Instead of pasting a block of code in here, explain it a bit & explain **why** this fixes the issue.