# How can I make a bot that listens for events but also has commands in discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need my discord bot to listen for events and I need it to have commands. Here is an example of my problem

```
import os
from keepalive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

banned_words = [
"blah", "blahh", "blahhh"
]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    msg = message.content
    msgsend = message.channel.send

    if any(word in msg.lower() for word in banned_words):
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await msgsend("Please don't use banned words!")

@client.command()
async def dice(message, amount:int):
    await message.channel.send("blah blah blah")
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working) might help you. Also take in ```ctx``` as a parameter instead of ```message``` for the command and send the message In the following way ```await ctx.send("blah blah")```

Answer (score 3):

Add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the beggining of your `on_message` event. This code process commands and allow users to invoke/use them.

Comment: Thanks, Ratery! This helped me a lot, and now my code is working. When someone joins or leaves the server I made an event which for some reason isn't working? If you know how I can solve this that would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @MM4760 Maybe you haven’t enabled members intents. Enable it in Discord developers portal and then add kwarg `intents=discord.Intents.all()` to your client definition. Like `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())`