# Discord.py on_message event isn't processing any commands - Modmail Event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a mod-mail feature which members can message the bot and it will respond with instructions. However the event works fine with the exception of bot commands. Here is my code. Strangely no errors were detected.

```py
sent_users = []
modmail_channel = client.get_channel(910023874727542794)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild:
        return
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.id in sent_users:
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(color = color)
    embed.set_author(name=f"Misaland Modmail System", icon_url=f'{message.author.avatar_url}')
    embed.add_field(name='Report a Member: ', value=f"React with <:Wojak1:917122152078147615> if you would like to report a member.")
    embed.add_field(name='Report a Staff Member:', value=f"React with <:grim1:925758467099222066> if you would like to report a staff.")
    embed.add_field(name='Warn Appeal:', value=f"React with <:Lovecat:919055184125100102> if you would like to appeal a warning.")
    embed.add_field(name='Question:', value=f"React with <:gasm:917112456776679575> if you have a question about the server")
    embed.add_field(name='Leave a Review', value=f"React with <:surebuddy1:917122193287163924> to leave a review about the server")
    embed.add_field(name='Server Invite', value=f'React with <:smirk:910565317363773511> to get the server invite.')
    embed.set_footer(text='Any questions asked that isnt related to the list, you will be severely abused')
    msg = await message.author.send(embed=embed)

    await msg.add_reaction("<:Wojak1:917122152078147615>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:grim1:925758467099222066>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:Lovecat:919055184125100102>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:gasm:917112456776679575>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:surebuddy1:917122193287163924>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<:smirk:910565317363773511>")

    sent_users.append(message.author.id)

    try:
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['<:Wojak1:917122152078147615>', '<:grim1:925758467099222066>','<:Lovecat:919055184125100102>','<:gasm:917112456776679575>','<:surebuddy1:917122193287163924>','<:smirk:910565317363773511>']

        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
        

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:Wojak1:917122152078147615>":
            embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
            embed.set_author(name=f"Misaland Member Report", icon_url=f'{message.author.avatar_url}')
            embed.add_field(name="How to Report:", value="Send the ID of the person you are reporting and attach a screenshot breaking the rules")
            embed.set_footer(text="Misaland | Member Report")
            await message.author.send(embed = embed)

            message = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=60, check=lambda m: m.channel == message.channel and m.author == message.author)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message.content}", color=color)
            await modmail_channel.send(embed=embed)
        
            
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: where have you processed commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

at the end of your code in

```
async def on_message(message):
```

If you're using commands outside of on_message, it's overridden