# If Discord.py Bot gets dm

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Dear stackoverflow community.
I want to add a little 'Easter egg' to my discord.py bot. If one gets a DM from a user, he should reply something like "No private messages while at work". Is that somehow possible? Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this. That's why I can't attach code. Please help me : )

Comment: Just use `on_message` and check is it in DM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an `on_message` event, which will fire each time there is any new message which your bot can read. Then you can check if the message is a direct message:

```py
@bot.event # could be client instead of bot for you
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: # Don't reply to itself. Could again be client for you
        return
    if isinstance(message.channel,discord.DMChannel): #If you want this to work in a group channel, you could also check for discord.GroupChannel
        await message.channel.send("No private messages while at work")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Also don't forget to add `bot.process_commands(message)` add the end of `on_message` so your commands still work. (Could again be client instead of bot for you)

### References:

- [Message.channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.Message.channel)

Comment: It works. Not really. I get the message, but the bot keeps sending me this message. He spams me with it. And could you please add `bot.process_commands(message)`  to the code. Don't know exactly what you mean by that. Thank you.

Comment: @jcjms I fixed the code. Also you only need `bot.process_commands(message)` if you have commands, since you are overwriting the default on message, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Comment: I think you forgot the 'await' before it. Added it and it works great. Please add this to your answer in case other users look at it. Thank you for your help! : )

Comment: Yes you're right, changed it.