# Unable to use any other commands after making event to delete messages within a channel Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I made a simple event to delete all messages with attachments within a channel
and now commands within my bot are not working as intended

**the event**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.attachments and message.channel.id == 957450518463119400:
  await message.delete()
 if not message.attachments and message.channel.id == 957450518463119400:
  await message.send()
```

**an example of a command that isn't working** (not sending the "stop" message)

```
@client.command()
async def damndaniel(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send(f"stop")
```

there aren't any errors in terminal.
as soon as I remove **the event** the example command is working fine

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Try replace `ctx: commands.Context` to `ctx`. Normaly the first parameter for function of discord application command is `ctx` only.

Comment: Do you know what type hints are? @SorryformybadEnglish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override the `on_message()` event, you need to add `client.process_commands()` to your event manually so it should be like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.attachments and message.channel.id == 957450518463119400:
  await message.delete()

 if not message.attachments and message.channel.id == 957450518463119400:
  await message.send()
 
 await client.process_commands(message)
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)