# Discord.py google search

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I decided to somehow do a Google search through discord.py
wrote the code

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('just google'):
        searchContent = ""
        text = str(message.content).split(' ')
        for i in range(2, len(text)):
            searchContent = searchContent + text[i]

        for j in search(searchContent, tld="co.in", num=1, stop=1, pause=2):
            await message.channel.send(j)
```

used this to make it all work:
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install google

the command works, but the rest of the bot commands do not work
like

```
@bot.command()
async def Meme(ctx):
```

here most likely you need to rework the beginning of the code for a similar
like

```
@bot.event
async def google(ctx):
        searchContent = ""
        text = str(message.content).split(' ')
        for i in range(2, len(text)):
            searchContent = searchContent + text[i]

        for j in search(searchContent, tld="co.in", num=1, stop=1, pause=2):
            await message.channel.send(j)
```

but this code only shows how to do it, it won't work.
in fact I don't know how to make something similar to the last code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Comment: nope,it didn't change anything at all

Comment: @Code You added `await bot.process_commands()` to the start of on_message and the commands still don't fire?

Comment: yes,this is dont work

Comment: I could not reproduce this, then.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you have overwritten the `on_message` event.

I recommend you to do the "Google command" as a `@bot.command()`

Anyway you can also just put this on the end of the `on_message` event:

`await bot.process_commands(message)`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

this will call the coroutine that is on the original `on_message`

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions