# clear command just doesn't work discord.py 2.0

Tags: python, discord

i have been fiddiling with this for the last 2 hours and don't understand why it doesnt work, i have message intents enabled, i have establisbed the commands properly, i am using the right prefix and amount. I've looked over my code multiple times but still do not see or understand why nothing happens, literally nothing happens lol.

```
from dis import dis
from importlib.metadata import requires
from sys import prefix
from unicodedata import name
from click import command, pass_context
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import requests
import asyncio

with open('badwords.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

intents = discord.Intents.default()


intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True


print(discord.__version__)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} is Online!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author != bot.user:
        for text in data['words']:
            if text in msg.content or text.upper() in msg.content or text.capitalize() in msg.content:
                await msg.delete()
                return
    
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, limit: int):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, your 'on_message' event is blocking all other commands from running.

[From the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

> Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a bot.process_commands(message) line at the end of your on_message. For example:
>
> ```
> async def on_message(message):
>    # do some extra stuff here
>
>    await bot.process_commands(message)
> ```

The default on_message contains a call to this coroutine, but when you override it with your own on_message, you need to call it yourself.

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Edit: In regards to your comment, I assume that you added the 'process_commands' in the wrong place. If I'm not mistaken, then your code should look something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author != bot.user:
        for text in data['words']:
            if text in msg.content or text.upper() in msg.content or text.capitalize() in msg.content:
                await msg.delete()
                return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Im getting this error   File "/home/exodus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1269, in process_commands
    if message.author.bot:
AttributeError: module 'email.message' has no attribute 'author'

Comment: The code at the bottom would result in a `NameError` (what is `message`?). Also, please flag as a duplicate instead of posting a duplicate answer.