# How to create a 'Delete X amount of messages' event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanted to create a `@client.event` that deletes the x amount of messages in the channel that activated the command. For example `!clear 5`, this would clear the last 5 messages sent in the channel, minus the command message. I used a `@client.command()` previously which seems to work however when I add that to my music bot which uses @client.event only, it just doesn't work. I'm not entirely sure why this is but I was hoping there was someone who can help me out with this. I can paste the entire code if needed.

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

This is the code I would like to be transfered over to a `@client.event` unless someone can help me figure out why a `.command` isn't working in the code.

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import requests

# Bot Initialization #

client = discord.Client()
token = "REMOVED"
api_key = "REMOVED"

##_SETTING THE PREFIX OF THE BOT_##
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*')

##_Bot Voice Setup_##
voice_clients = {}
yt_dl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)
ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}

##_BOT IS READY MESSAGE_##
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Bot logged in as {client.user}")


##_MUSIC PLAY_##
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content.startswith("*play"):

        try:
            voice_client = await msg.author.voice.channel.connect()
            voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client
        except:
            print("error")

        try:
            url = msg.content.split()[1]

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))

            song = data['url']
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options)

            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].play(player)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

##_MUSIC PAUSE_##
    if msg.content.startswith("*pause"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].pause()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

##_MUSIC RESUME_##
    if msg.content.startswith("*resume"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].resume()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

##_MUSIC STOP + DISCONNECT_##
    if msg.content.startswith("*stop"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].stop()
            await voice_clients[msg.guild.id].disconnect()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

##_SKIP CURRENT SONG_##
    if msg.content.startswith("*skip"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].skip()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Why can't you use commands extension here? If you really need to, you can also do `message.channel` and then `that.purge(args)`.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I tried reimporting everything but nothing seems to be fixing it

Comment: Does a random command work? `@client.command()` then `async def test(ctx):` then `await ctx.send('a')`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had to step away for a bit. I tried adding a test command and its not doing anything, at all. There aren't any error messages or anything coming up in the terminal either, I'm stumped

edit: I tripled checked my imports, spelling. and indenting and nothing seems to be out of place so I'm extremely lost

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working @Shineori

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either :\ I'm still getting nothing in the console nor am I getting anything in discord

Comment: I realized I used the `client` variable twice, is that maybe a cause for issue?

Comment: So you can't just add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to the end? Using the decorator as you did there is still correct, there's nothing wrong with that. Do you have messages intents enabled? Does a stripped down version of the bot work?

Comment: I would recommend turning all of the commands into actual commands instead of message events if possible, and can you send your code after you added the `bot.process_commands` bit