# Commands not working from discord.ext import commands

Tags: discord, discord.py, command

So basically I have this problem, any command that I type does not work. There are no errors, and everything else is working fine. It's just that for some reasons @bot.command() isn't working, and that is kind of annoying.

```py
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
import time


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

intents.message_content = True 


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)

TOKEN = 'hi'

ROLE = 'hi'


db1 = [hi, hi]


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
    await bot.process_commands(arg)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  role = get(member.guild.roles, name=ROLE)
  await member.add_roles(role)
  await member.send('hi')
  try:
        channel = member.guild.system_channel
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Welcome <@{}> in {} ".format(str(member.id),str(member.guild)), description="Cheapest coins on the market", color=0x00ff00)
        await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
  except:
        channel = member.guild.get_channel(hi)
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Welcome <@{}> in {} ".format(str(member.id),str(member.guild)), description="Cheapest coins on the market", color=0x00ff00)
        await channel.send(embed=embedVar)

           
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  try:
        channel = member.guild.system_channel
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Bye {} from {} ".format(str(member.name),str(member.guild)), description="Come back when you want", color=0x00ff00)
        await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
  except:
        channel = member.guild.get_channel(hi)
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Bye {} from {} ".format(str(member.name),str(member.guild)), description="Come back when you want", color=0x00ff00)
        await channel.send(embed=embedVar)

@bot.event
async def on_invite_create(invite):
  channel = bot.get_channel(hi)
  await channel.send("An invite has been created, {}, by <@{}> on {}".format(str(invite.url), str(invite.inviter.id), str(invite.created_at)))


@bot.event
async def on_invite_delete(invite):
  channel = bot.get_channel(hi)
  await channel.send("An invite has been deleted by{}".format(str(invite.inviter.id)))

  
@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(hi)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description="Ban requested on<@{}>".format(str(member.id)))
    await channel.send(embed=embedVar)


@bot.event
async def on_member_unban(guild, member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(hi)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Unban", description="Unban requested on<@{}>".format(str(member.id)))
    await channel.send(embed=embedVar)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} succesfully logged in')
    return


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('purge requested by'):
    time.sleep(1)
    await message.delete()
  if message.author == bot:
    return
  if message.content == 'hi':
    await message.channel.send('hi')
  if message.content.startswith('binvites'):
        totalInvites = 0
        for i in await message.guild.invites():
            if i.inviter == message.author:
                totalInvites += i.uses
        await message.channel.send(f"You have invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the Central Trade server")
  if message.content == 'bpurge':
    if message.author.id in db1:
      await message.channel.purge(limit=10)
      await message.channel.send('purge requested by <@{}>'.format(str(message.author.id)))
    else:
      return
  if message.content == 'block':
    if message.author.id in db1:
      channel = message.channel
      overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(message.guild.default_role)
      overwrite.send_messages = False
      await channel.set_permissions(message.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
      embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Lock", description="Channel lock request by <@{}>".format(str(message.author.id)), color= 0x00FFFF)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
      await message.author.send('You do not have the permission to use this command')
  if message.content == 'bunlock':
    if message.author.id in db1:
      channel = message.channel
      overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(message.guild.default_role)
      overwrite.send_messages = True
      await channel.set_permissions(message.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
      embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Unlock", description="Channel unlock request by <@{}>".format(str(message.author.id)), color=0xC0C0C0)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
      await message.author.send('You do not have the permission to use this command')
  if message.content == 'test':
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="test", description="test", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="test", value="test", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
  if message.content == 'bpurges':
    if message.author.id in db1:
      await message.channel.purge(limit=10000)
      await message.channel.send('purge requested by <@{}>'.format(str(message.author.id)))
      embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Purge", description="Purge requested by<@{}>".format(str(message.author.id)))
      await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
      time.sleep(1)
      await message.channel.delete()



    

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Anyone has an idea why it's not working ?
Also seems like i need to post more details, don't pay attention to this :
Roméo et Juliette (Romeo and Juliet) est une tragédie de William Shakespeare.

Comment: Does the bot appear as online? Is there any error?

Comment: I of course have the run(token), everything works excepted with @bot.command()

Comment: yes it does and no there isnt any error

Comment: What's your version? Also try `intents.message_content = True`

Comment: I use discord.py 1.7.3

Comment: Can you add the complete code to your question? There might be other events messing with the commands.

Comment: alright i completed the code

Comment: also don't mind the "hi" its just some sensible stuff that i censored into hi

Comment: You need to process commands in `on_message` - it does that by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)