# whenever i put a event (on_message) in my code my commands don't work discord.py 3

Tags: discord.py

Heres The Code: (I want to be able to use commands and have events working at the same time, Yes the on_ready event does work at all times, Its a selfbot)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hey it looks like you already have a full bank BUD":
        await message.channel.send('pls use banknote')

@bot.command()
async def d(ctx):
 print(Fore.BLUE + ('Running Farmer 1.0 - Dank Memer') + Fore.RESET)
 while True:
  await ctx.send('pls fish')
  await ctx.send('pls dig')
  await ctx.send('pls hunt')
  await ctx.send('pls beg')
  await ctx.send('pls dep all')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

to the end of your `on_message`.

Consider checking the FAQ: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working