# Something is wrong with @client.command() and I can't find the mistake. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Commands are imported from discord.ext. The PREF is '!'.

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREF)`

This event below is working.

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    wordd = 'say home'
    if wordd in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("home")
```

But this command below is not working...

```
@client.command()
async def welcome(ctx):
    tablica = ["czesc", "siema", "witaj"]
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(tablica))
```

Anyone help?

'

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



PREF = '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREF)
client.remove_command("help")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    wordd = 'say home'
    if wordd in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("home")



@client.command()
async def welcome(ctx):
    tablica = ["czesc", "siema", "witaj"]
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(tablica))





client.run(<token>)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the on_message command

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



PREF = '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREF)
client.remove_command("help")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    wordd = 'say home'
    if wordd in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("home")
    await client.process_commands(message)



@client.command()
async def welcome(ctx):
    tablica = ["czesc", "siema", "witaj"]
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(tablica))





client.run(<token>)
```

[DOCS](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)