# Discord bot doesn't gets triggered on using commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, pycord

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from replit import db


#setting up bot
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True
intents.presences = True
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents , command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="your mom"))

   
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("your balance is $0")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if msg.startswith('hello'):
      await message.channel.send('hello')
```

This is the code, and I have double checked everything. The bot is online and it does replies to Hello but when typing `!balance` it doesn't gets triggered at all. There is no error in console either. I even tried `Try:` to check for some hidden errors but none. I also checked dev portals and the bot does have all the required permissions.

what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message() stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to tell the bot to process the commands in your message. It does this by default, but you have overridden that with the `on_message()` event. All you need is to include `bot.process_commands(message)` in the on_message event.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if msg.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')
```

Comment: It's replying fine to the hello though, It's not replying to my !balance command

Comment: hello, it got fixed, thank you

Comment: Great! Could you check my answer as correct thanks :)

Comment: okay it's done :D