# python discord bot command sudenly stopped working, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: Image of my code]

I started making this bot, and this is just a small info command with an embed. After I made a DM support system this command stopped working, can anyone notice anything wrong with it?

I tried to change a bit of the code that didn't work.

Comment: Please don't use images to show your code, but rather paste it into your question directly.

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have it for my DM system. why?

Comment: @Dominik ^^^^^^

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working

Comment: @Dominik I have just done this and it still have not worked

Comment: Try `ctx.send` instead of `ctx.reply`

Comment: @Dominik its still not working I am going to try and remove the DM system see if that changes anything.

Comment: Could you paste your on_message code?

Comment: @PedroCaribé It has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the default provided `on_message` forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message`. For example:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The default `on_message` contains a call to this coroutine, but when you override it with your own `on_message`, you need to call it yourself.