# Why isn't my discord bot answering when I type the command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

So im doing a **python discord bot** using *discord.py* library and it worked perfectly until I tried to switch on a version of the code using the **slashcommands**. I have no error at all in the logs...
Here is my code :

***main.py***

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import date, timedelta
from icalendar import Calendar
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from config import TOKEN, CHANNEL_ID

keep_alive()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  # Ignore messages from the bot itself
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def date(ctx):
  todaydate = date.today()
  d1 = todaydate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  await ctx.send('Nous sommes le ' + str(d1))


@client.command()
async def cours(ctx, *args):
  if not args:
    await ctx.send(
        "Veuillez spécifier 'today' ou 'demain' après la commande $cours.")
    return

  if args[0].lower() == 'today':
    await display_courses(ctx, date.today())
  elif args[0].lower() == 'demain':
    await display_courses(ctx, date.today() + timedelta(days=1))
  else:
    await ctx.send(
        "Argument non reconnu. Utilisez 'today' ou 'demain' après la commande $cours."
    )


async def display_courses(ctx, target_date):
  courses = []
  horaires = []
  locations = []

  e = open('Agenda/groupeD.ics', 'rb')
  ecal = Calendar.from_ical(e.read())  #Récupérer le calendar pepal

  todaydate = date.today()
  d2 = todaydate.strftime("%Y%m%d")  #Formatage de la date

  # Ajout : définir la variable datejour
  datejour = todaydate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

  for event in ecal.walk('VEVENT'):
    Aevent = event.get("DTSTART")
    step = Aevent.dt
    d3 = step.strftime("%Y%m%d")  #Récupération et formatage date cible
    horaire = step.strftime("%Hh%M")
    location = event.get("LOCATION")

    if d3 == d2:
      courses.append(event.get("SUMMARY"))  #Ajouter
      horaires.append(horaire)
      locations.append(location)

  e.close()

  embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f"Emploi du temps {datejour}",
                           description="Aujourd'hui vous avez : ",
                           color=0x3853B4)
  if len(courses) > 0:
    embedVar.add_field(name=courses[0],
                       value=f"{horaires[0]} en **{locations[0].lower()}**",
                       inline=False)
    if len(courses) > 1:
      embedVar.add_field(name=courses[1],
                         value=f"{horaires[1]} en **{locations[1].lower()}**",
                         inline=False)
  else:
    embedVar.add_field(name="Pas de cours",
                       value="Aucun cours pour aujourd'hui.",
                       inline=False)

  await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  # ... (your existing code for $ping)
  pass


# Easter egg
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('42'):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(
        title="42",
        description=
        "La solution à la grande question sur la vie, l'univers , et le reste, assurément...",
        color=0x3853B4)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

The bot runs on Repl.it and is maintained by UptimeRobot, btw thank you in advance !

Comment: I would be good if we know the version, the command you have the issue with, things like that.

Comment: the command i have a issue with is $cours today, and all the others. Im using the last version of python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message() stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Comment: Do you have the proper intents?

Comment: Yes I have all the proper intents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are still using CTX for slash commands.

```
@client.command()
async def date(ctx):
  todaydate = date.today()
  d1 = todaydate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  await ctx.send('Nous sommes le ' + str(d1))
```

however, for slash commands, you need discord.Interaction, or it wont show up as a slash command. Its not giving you an error because nothing is truley wrong with your code, just a couple module that were imported but never used (usally underlined in yellow)

Here is the updated code for that block of code, remember to do this for all other code blocks as well.

```
@client.command(name="date", description="WHATEVER_YOUR_DESCRIPTION_IS")
async def date(interation: discord.Interaction):
  todaydate = datetime.utcnow() # Using UTC time is more reliable #compensate your timezone by using real_today = todaydate [+ or -] timedelta(hours=?)
  d1 = todaydate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  await interaction.response.send_message('Nous sommes le ' + str(d1))
```

These are the only imports you need to make this work:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
```

Hope this helps! If so, mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: @client.command() is not slash command
Slash command is: client.tree.command, app_commands.command or client.hybrid_command

Comment: Ill go test that

Comment: I applied all of your 2 answers together and I got this error : 
"discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "date" is not found"

Comment: Resolved, the first version was good !